# Why ListView.getChildAt(i) return null while iterating to retrieve value from edittext field and textview in button click event

Tags: android, listview

In my listview, there is edittext field for each row. When I click "submit" button, I iterated all the rows and try to get the value from text field and edit text field. Eg, there are five rows in list view. user can see Only three rows at a time. User need to scroll to see the other rows.
When I click on "Submit" button below listview, I iterate all the rows and try to get the values. If the items is out of visible, it always return null. 
Thus, how should I try to get the value of edit text field which is out of screen.

ListView Layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_tv1"
                android:layout_width="140dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/tv1" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_tv2"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/tv2" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_tv3"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/tv3" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

List View Item Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pck_tv1"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="AAAA" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pck_tv2"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="BBB" /> 
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />  
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_pck_edt1"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Button On Click Event

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_submit: {
        int count = 0;

        EditText mTxtEdt1;
        TextView mTxtTv1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getCount(); i++) {
            v = mListView.getChildAt(i);
            mTxtTv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_pck_tv1);
            mTxtEdt1;= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_pck_edt1);
            String tvValue = mTxtTv1.getText().toString();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

v = mListView.getChildAt(i); return null when the child is out of view. 
So how to get the value from it.
Any Suggestion???

Comment: You should better do it in your ListAdapter..!!

Comment: You are storing your view in the argument view of the method. Just try making a new View variable. Inside your loop, first make the argument null and then initialise it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is one thing about the ListView it only gives you the views for those which are present on the screen at current time. So you will have to save or maintain data when your views are on screen and changed rather then getting them on a button click.

For example you can use TextWatcher to listen onTextChanged event of both and save data there on the basis of listview adapter position.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise. I tried to get correct value onTextChange event in Listview adapter position. Now it is working well already.